# Install PL/Perl in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, perl, postgresql

I using PostgreSQL and I want to create a function in pl/perl, but the PostgreSQL doesn't contain pl/perl.

When I type `createlang plperlu databasename` it shows:

> createlang: language installation failed: ERROR : could not open
>   extension control file
>   "/usr/local/pgsql/share/extension/plperlu.control": No such file or
>   directory

How can I install plperlu?

The PostgreSQL version is 9.1 in CentOS 5.8

Comment: You're probably missing the contrib modules. How'd you install PostgreSQL? From `yum.postgresql.org` ?

Comment: Hi, i don't know, my colleague install it. How can i solve it? Thanks,

Comment: Ask your colleague? Or post the output of `rpm -qa |grep postgresql` and `rpm -qi postgresql`

Comment: Thanks, the first one output is postgresql-libs-8.1.23-4.el5_8
second one package postgresql is not installed.

Comment: Well, that's PostgreSQL 8.1, and you said you had 9.1. Are there no other lines output? What happens if you type `which psql`? I'm wondering if your co-worker installed from source code, in which case you'll probably have to recompile to get plperl.

Comment: Thanks, when i type which psql. output is /usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql.how can i get plperl. I'm newcomer in linux and postgresql. Thanks,

Comment: In CentOS you to install postgresql-plperl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before you do anything else, back up your database. At minimum use `pg_dump` to take a SQL dump and put it on another computer. Then proceed, but understand that you're likely to cause downtime or even data loss if you muck this up.

(For anyone else reading this, it only applies to PostgreSQL **installed from source code**. You are probably using a packaged version instead, in which case you should install the package for postgresql-contrib or postgresql-plperl for your distro. Names will vary, so do a search in your package management system.)

---

It seems highly likely that your co-worker installed PostgreSQL from source code and didn't enable PL/Perl. If you want PL/Perl you will need to re-compile.

Install the Perl development package, which should be called `perl-devel`, eg:

```
yum install perl-devel
```

When you re-compile PostgreSQL use the `--with-perl` argument to `./configure`. You should be able to find the PostgreSQL source code tree that your co-worker used somewhere on the system - try searching for `config.log` and see if there's a PostgreSQL source code tree in the same place.

If you can't find it you'll have to either:

- Download fresh PostgreSQL sources and compile them as per the PostgreSQL documentation; or
- Shut down your current server and install the [yum.postgresql.org](http://yum.postgresql.org) RPMs to replace it.

Honestly, if you don't know Linux this isn't a good way to start. Find somebody to help you who's worked with Linux systems before and is familiar with basic tasks like installing packages. Get them to help you to replace the source-installed PostgreSQL with  a PostgreSQL install from the [yum.postgresql.org](http://yum.postgresql.org) packages, and preferably update your rather outdated operating system install to a current one.

Comment: For users using packages rather than installing from source, @DaveJarvis commented: "On CentOS, try: yum install postgresql91-plperl.x86_64" as an edit.